# While migrating Java play from 2.3 to 2.4 getting error

Tags: java, playframework

I have followed the migration guide and made changes to routes file in java play, however when i hit application URL i get the exception as

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V from class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:169) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V from class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module.<init>(JSR310Module.java:142) ~[jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at play.libs.Json.newDefaultMapper(Json.java:31) ~[play-json_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.libs.Json.<clinit>(Json.java:25) ~[play-json_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.core.ObjectMapperProvider.get$lzycompute(ObjectMapperModule.scala:33) ~[play-java_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.core.ObjectMapperProvider.get(ObjectMapperModule.scala:31) ~[play-java_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.core.ObjectMapperProvider.get(ObjectMapperModule.scala:30) ~[play-java_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126) ~[play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93) ~[play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:153) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Has any one else got such exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you don't have an older jackson jar around your project. Specifically look under your /lib folder and check your dependency tree.

Comment: Leandro, indeed problem was with the version, however, i had moved latest jackson jarsto my lib to get it resolve, i hadupdated it in other group forgot to mention out here, but yes u are correct.